# Home tabs display "expand" text when highlighted instead of drop down arrow

Tags: bug, new-nav, homepage

It's a minor thing, but I accidentally highlighted some content on the home page and noticed that some text showed up in the menu tabs on the home page, saying: `expand` instead of displaying an arrow. Below is the drop down control (not highlighted) and markup that holds the text:

[image]

Here is the content when highlighted, with `expand` text showing instead of the drop down arrow:

[image]

I tested removing the `expand` text in the markup and it works without issue, so I guess it can be removed?

[image]

Comment: BTW i'm using chrome latest.